# Remove ads button on ad control

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to insert small close/remove icon in ad control corner that will open marketplace with ad free version of my app. Something like that was in 6tag (it was actually in app purchase but all in all its similar).

My only concern is Microsoft might not like it. What do you think about that? Will my certification may fail because of that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Will my certification may fail because of that?` It won't. PubCenter and the marketplace are two different things.

As to know whether you're allowed to do that or not, the [PubCenter terms](https://pubcenter.microsoft.com/CustomerManagement/Customer/TC.html) leave no ambiguity on the matter:

> 6/   **Prohibitions.**  You may only use the Service as expressly permitted in this Agreement and you must comply with any technical limitations of the Service that allow you to use it only in certain ways. You will not do any of the following with respect to the Service:
>
> [...]
>
> - **edit, resize, modify, filter, obscure, hide, make transparent or reorder any advertising (including their associated links) supplied by the Service;**

Overlaying an icon on top of the ad would definitely count as modifying or obscuring.